# Finding all monic polynomials of degree $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I find monic divisors of degree 1 for a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$? 
More specifically $$f (x)=x^4+x^3+x+4.$$
I am not sure how to even begin the problem

Comment: Monic means leading coefficient is $1$. Linear means $ax+b$. Put the two together and you only have a few things to check by polynomial division...

Comment: So would the only monic divisor of degree 1 be x?

Comment: That seems too simple.

Comment: Think of $x$ as $(x - 0)$. You need to check $(x-1)$ ... Up until [what]?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: check out the [factor theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

Then notice that there are only five elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

$f(0)=4 \neq 0$, so $x$ is not a factor.

$f(1)= 1+1+1+4 = 2 \neq 0$, so $x-1$ is not a factor.

Etc.